# ubuntu16.04 system keeps reporting errors when installing milvus CPU version

Tags: docker, vector, installation

I installed it by following the instruction from [Milvus](https://milvus.io/docs/milvus_docker-gpu.md). But every time I installed it with docker, it failed to start.

The docker command is as followed:

```
sudo docker run -d --name milvus_cpu_0.10.5 \
-p 19530:19530 \
-p 19121:19121 \
-v /home/$USER/milvus/db:/var/lib/milvus/db \
-v /home/$USER/milvus/conf:/var/lib/milvus/conf \
-v /home/$USER/milvus/logs:/var/lib/milvus/logs \
-v /home/$USER/milvus/wal:/var/lib/milvus/wal \
milvusdb/milvus:0.10.5-cpu-d010621-4eda95
```

And `docker logs` didn't show any information.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNBNg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many factors might cause this problem. First, make sure that your machine supports these instruction sets. [image]

Comment: I use another machine that supports avx2 intruction set, and then milvus works well. Thanks!